# isalpha() detects non-alphabetic character with no input

Tags: c

I am currently on a beginner course in C and was given an exercise requiring my program to check if the user input contains non-alphabets. I've figured to use the function `isalpha()` to check the user input and if it contains non-alphabets, the program should ask the user to enter another input.

Below is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX 13

int main() {
  char player1[MAX];
  int k = 0;

  // Ask player 1 to type a word.
  printf("Player 1, enter a word of no more than 12 letters: \n");
  fgets(player1, MAX, stdin);

  // // Loop over the word entered by player1 
  for (int i = 0; i < player1[i]; i++) {
    // if any chars looped through is not an alphabet, print message.
    if (isalpha((unsigned char)player1[i]) == 0) {
      printf("Sorry, the word must contain only English letters.");
    }
  }
```

However, after testing it, I've derived a few cases from its results.

Case 1:
Entering without any input prints `("Sorry, the word must contain only English letters. ")`

Case 2:
An input with 1 non-alphabetic character prints the 'sorry' message twice. Additionally, an input with 2 non-alphabetic characters print the 'sorry' message thrice. This implies that case 1 is true, since no input prints the message once, then adding a non-alphabetic prints the message twice.

Case 3:
An input of less than 10 characters(all alphabetic) prints out the sorry message also.

Case 4:
An input of more than 9 characters(all alphabetic) does not print out the sorry message, which satisfies my requirements.

Why are these the cases? I only require the message to print once if after looping through the user input, there's found to be a non-alphabetic character!

Comment: Case 2: Message can appear twice since you don't break the loop on first error detected. Case 1 and 3: You don't loop until end of string, but until end of array, so you'll meet '\0' when array contains less than 12 characters, which is not is range for isalpha() ((>= '0 && <= '9') || (>= 'A' && <= 'z')).

Comment: Range is  (>= 'A' && <= 'Z') || (>= 'a' && <= 'z')), misread isalpha() as isalphanum(), https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/ctype.h/isalpha.

Comment: `i < player1[i]` makes no sense as the test condition in that for loop.

Comment: And you're not accounting for the newline in the string, which of course fails `isalpha()`.

Comment: @AR7CORE your comment suggests that I loop until end of string. However from my understanding, a string in C is just an array of chars? How do you suggest I edit my code then?

Comment: @Shawn what do you mean by newline in the string? Kindly elaborate.

Comment: Strings are just null-terminated array of chars, arrays are just const pointer to the first element, but iterating until end of array might go further than string's null-terminating byte (ascii 0). What you want is maxIndex = min(strlen(player1), 13), to stop on first condition met: 1) end of array to prevent reading further than array size(not likely since you specified size with fgets(), as Shawn underlined), 2) end of string to not read '\0' which fails isalpha()

Comment: You have an array, of size 13, so if your string is for example 3 chars long ("bar"), your array contains { 'b', 'a', 'r', '\0', garbage * 9 }, and garbage has a very high probability to contain bytes which aren't in letters range in ascii table. The thing is you iterate over the whole array, even if contained string was smaller.

Comment: @AR7CORE I've read your comments but the jargon makes it difficult to understand. If possible, kindly write an answer in code for my understanding. I'm just starting out in C.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < player1[i]; i++)`?? You mean `for (int i = 0; player1[i]; i++)`... As you have it written any char larger than `'\r'` would cause reading beyond your array bounds. See [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: @AR7CORE User input is very unlikely to be `"bar"`, but `"bar\n"` and the array then contains  { 'b', 'a', 'r', '\n', '\0', garbage * 8 }, not  { 'b', 'a', 'r', '\0', garbage * 9 }.

Comment: @BrioTech "Case 1: Entering without any input prints" never happens as the input contains a `'\n'` and then `player1[]` is  `'\n'`, `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in C are null-terminated, which means they contains an extra byte '\0' to mark the end of the string (character 0 in the ascii table), so you can only store 12 characters in a char array of size 13.

If you array contains a string smaller than 12 characters, since you loop over the whole array, you'll meet that null-terminating-byte, which fails isalpha(): it checks if character is in range ['A', 'Z'] or ['a', 'z']. Characters are just integers for your computers, so isalpha() checks if received value is is range [65, 90] or [97, 122], and 0 is not.
To be more precise, the notion of integer makes no sense for your computer, that's just how we interpret information, it's just a bunch of bits for your computer.

See ascii table: https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html

By having a fixed size buffer, you'll have garbage after the contained string if the string doesn't take all the space.

You have 2 conditions to stop iterating:

- end of array, to prevent overflowing the array
- end of string, to prevent mis-interpreting bytes in array which are further than string end

Error message might be printed several times, since you keep checking even after an error occured, you have to break the loop.

Below code doesn't meet mentioned problems

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 13

#define MIN(a, b) (a < b ? a : b)

int main(void)
{
    char player1[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int maxIndex;
    int i;

    /* Ask player 1 to type a word */
    printf("Player 1, enter a word of no more than 12 letters: \n");
    fgets(player1, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);

    /*
     * Max index for iteration, if string is lesser than 12 characters
     * (excluding null-terminating byte '\0') stop on string end, otherwise
     * loop over whole array
     */
    maxIndex = MIN(strlen(player1) - 1, BUFFER_SIZE);

    for (i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++) {
        /* Print error if non-letters were entered */
        if (isalpha(player1[i]) == 0) {
            printf("Sorry, the word must contain only English letters.");
            /* Error occured, no need to check further */
            break;
        }
    }

    /*
    for (i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++)
        printf("%d ", (int) player1[i]);
    printf("\n%s\n", player1);*/

    return 0;
}
```

The MIN() is a macro, a ternary expression which returns the smallest argument, nothing really complicated here.

But note that, when you enter the word, you press <Enter>, so your string contains a "go to next line" character (character '\n', n°10 in ascii table, as @Shawn mentioned in comments), so you have to stop before it: that's why I use `strlen(player) - 1`, string ends with "\n\0", and strlen() returns the number of bytes before '\0' (including '\n').

I've let a dump of the string at the end, you can modify the end-index there to see what's sent to isalpha(), replace maxIndex with BUFFER_SIZE.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation. Now I know where those 'ghost' characters are coming from! Will accept this answer.

Comment: Advanced: `MIN(strlen(player1) - 1, BUFFER_SIZE)` is hacker exploit if the first character read by `fgets()` is a _null character_.

Comment: AR7CORE, This answer's concern for "end of array, to prevent overflowing the array" is unfounded.  When `fgets()` returns non-`NULL`, simply iterated to the _null character_ of the string in `player1[]`.  Code may want to also end the loop if `'\n'` detected.

Answer (score 2):

As @unwind has noted, the conditional of the OP `for()` loop is incorrect.

Good to trust to `isalpha()` but your code doesn't have to fondle each and every character. Another standard library function, `strspn()`, when supplied with your needs, can perform the looping work for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 12

int main() {
    char player1[ MAX + 1 + 1 ]; // buffer size for fgets() 12 + '\n' + '\0'
    char *permissible =
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    // Ask player 1 to type a word.
    printf("Player 1, enter a word of no more than %d letters: \n", MAX);
    fgets(player1, sizeof player1, stdin);

    if( player1[ strspn( player1, permissible ) ] != '\n' )
        printf("Sorry, the word must contain only English letters.");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
for (int i = 0; i < player1[i]; i++) {
```

loops from 0 up until (but not including) the code point value of the i:th character, updating `i` every time it loops. It will very likely access outside the array bounds, which is undefined behavior.

It should look for the terminator (or linefeed but let's keep it simple):

```
for (size_t i = 0; player1[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
```

Comment: Chuckling, you caught that too. Only took a hour for somebody to drop by that saw that glaring flashing red uh-oh...

Answer (score 1):

> to use the function isalpha() to check the user input and if it contains non-alphabets

Simply read one character at a time.  No maximum needed.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int ch;
  int all_alpha = 1;

  printf("Player 1, enter a line\n");

  while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    if (!isalpha(ch)  {
      all_alpha = 0;
    }
  }

  if (!all_alpha) {
    printf("Sorry, the line must contain only letters.");
  }
}
```